# Error while creating a proportions table in R: Error in table(st2.affect) : attempt to make a table with \>= 2^31 elements

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data, proportions

I got this error:

> Error in table(st2.affect) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

when I tried to use function (or any other proportions function) such as:

```
proportions(table(st2.affect), margin = 1L)
```

My dataset has 20 categorical variables with 5 levels which are very important for the analysis. I still tried to do the proportion table without levels and got the same error. I want to know frequencies and proportions of each variable and I want to create a table with proportions.

What is the solution to this error?

Data set sample:

There are 20 areas (variable)
Each participant assigned one of 5 affective labels

```r
 area1_affect area2_affect area3_affect area4_affect area5_affect 
 Peaceful     Peaceful     Peaceful     Tense        Peaceful       
 Other        Peaceful     Other        Other        Other           
 Peaceful     Peaceful     Peaceful     Tense        Tense           
 Peaceful     Tense        Delighted    Tense        Peaceful      
 Peaceful     Peaceful     Peaceful     Other        Other           
 Peaceful     Peaceful     Delighted    Tense        Tense
```

Comment: If you have 20 columns, each with 5 levels you end up with a table of 5^20~10^13 elements, most of them being zero. Are you sure you need the joint table and not a table for each column? Consider also to use `aggregate` or `dplyr::count` or the `.N` special value for `data.table`, which will list only the present combinations (and not all the possible combinations like `table`).

Comment: @AllanCameron Sorry, I am still learning, I added a data frame example, is it okay? Thank you!

Comment: @Ola Thanks. Are you perhaps looking for `lapply(st2.affect, function(x) table(x)/length(x))`?

Comment: @AllanCameron I get this output from function lapply that you sent `$area2_affect
area1_affect
 Depressed      Tense   Peaceful  Delighted      Other 
0.00000000 0.07446809 0.63829787 0.10638298 0.18085106` But are those proportions of area 2 only or a comparison of area 1 and area 2?

Comment: These are the proportions of the factor level within each column. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, it was, I just got confused over area1_affect being there with the results of every variable

Comment: @AllanCameron Sorry to disturb you again, but would you maybe know how to round to 2 decimal points all the proportions with R code? Thank you so much

Comment: Try `lapply(st2.affect, function(x) round(table(x)/length(x), 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try making `factor`s in columns with `unique` values as `levels=`.

```
> dat[1:5] <- lapply(dat[1:5], factor, levels=unique(unlist(dat[1:5])))
> t(sapply(dat[1:5], table)) |> proportions(margin=1L)
              Peaceful     Other     Tense Delighted
area1_affect 0.8333333 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
area2_affect 0.8333333 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000
area3_affect 0.5000000 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.3333333
area4_affect 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000
area5_affect 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(area1_affect = c("Peaceful", "Other", "Peaceful", 
"Peaceful", "Peaceful", "Peaceful"), area2_affect = c("Peaceful", 
"Peaceful", "Peaceful", "Tense", "Peaceful", "Peaceful"), area3_affect = c("Peaceful", 
"Other", "Peaceful", "Delighted", "Peaceful", "Delighted"), area4_affect = c("Tense", 
"Other", "Tense", "Tense", "Other", "Tense"), area5_affect = c("Peaceful", 
"Other", "Tense", "Peaceful", "Other", "Tense")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```